# Exceptions without stack traces in JBoss

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jboss, stack-trace

I have an NPE being thrown in controller method:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Controller {

    ...

    @PostConstruct
    @Override
    protected void init() {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    ...

}
```

and jboss log contains the following entry:

19:34:53,045 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance

The problem is that there is no stack trace. I've done a lot of googling and ran into several posts about the same problem, but those people were interested in solving the root cause of the exception, they managed to do that more or less, but I'm interested in the stack trace itself. I've tried custom exception handler (http://wmarkito.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/adding-global-exception-handling-using-jsf-2-x-exceptionhandler/) and primefaces exception handler (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/ajaxErrorHandler.jsf;jsessionid=1gvidy1bnjzr8jggq89l59gcs) with no success.

I would appreciate any ideas concerning why there is no stack trace in case of exception in controller method and how to deal with that.

Comment: Provide the relevant code to replicate the problem. AFAIK jboss logs contain the stacktrace of the exception thrown by default.

Comment: In case of other exceptions, for example transaction timeout, there is a stack trace, but for this specific situation there is no any for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exceptions thrown in @PostConstruct methods of controllers are not logged properly due the following reasons:
in org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent class every exceptions are catched and wrapped with IllegalStateException:

```
try {
    componentInstancePostConstructInterceptor.processInvocation(interceptorContext);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw MESSAGES.componentConstructionFailure(e);
}
```

and deep inside jboss internals, there is a class com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl that takes controll during components construction, with the following code:

```
try {
    // do the default behavior...
    comp.encodeAll(ctx);
}
catch (Exception ce) {
    if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.SEVERE)) {
    LOGGER.severe(ce.toString());
}
```

Not all of the components are affected